GitHistory not working with Vim extensions
When I add the Vim plugin for vscode (vscodevim.vim), it breaks my other plugin called GitHistory (donjayamanne.githistory)
The main feature it breaks is called "Git: View File History" in the command pallete.
The keybind is alt+h.
I tried disabling vim from messing with that keybind by adding
 "vim.handleKeys": {
    "<A-h>": false,
  }

To the settings.json. That worked in the past but it's not working anymore.
I don't know enough to be able to debug this. Any vscode input wizards out there?
